# yeoman angular not rendering views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, hapi.js

So, I've been trying to set up an app using Yeoman's official angular gen and [this hapijs generator](https://github.com/normative/generator-hapi-service) for the backend. Now, so far on the backend I've only got the home route serving the index.html as you can see here

```
  server.route({
    method: "GET",
      path: "/{param*}",
      handler: {
        directory: {
          path: ["../../client/app", "../../client/bower_components"]
        }
      },
      config: {
      auth: false
    }
  });

  next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'index'
};
```

The thing is that worked until I tried to add a new service, controller and view to the angular app, when I did so the views stopped rendering.

Heres the service:

```
angular.module('graphMeDota2App', [])
  .service('MatchesService', ['$httpq', 'config', function ($httpq, config) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    return {
        GetAllMatches: function(){
            return $httpq.get(config.steamApiBaseUrl + 'IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/v001/?key' + config.steamApiKey + '&accountId' + config.steamAccountId + '&matches_requested=5');
        }
    };
  }]);
```

Heres the controller:

```
angular.module('graphMeDota2App')
  .controller('MatchesCtrl', ['MatchesService', function ($scope, MatchesService) {
        $scope.matches = {};

        $scope.getMatches = function(){
            MatchesService.GetAllMatches().done(function(response){
                $scope.matches = response.data;
            });
        };

        $scope.getHeroPlayed = function(match){
            console.log(match);
            return 'asdfasdf';
        };
  }]);
```

Heres the view:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Match Id</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="match in matches">
      <th>{{$index}}</th>
      <th>{{match.match_id}}</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here's my app.js:

```
angular
  .module('graphMeDota2App', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .when('/matches', {
        templateUrl: 'views/matches.html',
        controller: 'MatchesCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

And finally, [this is what I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwDZY.jpg) .

There are no javascript errors, no server sider errors and the views were rendering perfectly before I added my controller/service (both added with the yeoman command line generator).

Comment: What happens if you step back a few steps and try adding things one at a time, checking the browser one at a time?

Comment: you forgot a `$scope` in MatchesCtrl

Comment: Lil' late reponse, but yeah. I encountered that error afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, following what Byron Sommardahl said found out the problem was when I was creating my service, specifically this line:

```
angular.module('graphMeDota2App', [])
  .service('MatchesService', ['$httpq', 'config', function ($httpq, config) {
```

Only thing I did was remove the first "[]" in the first line, then it started working. Any thoughts on why that happened?

```
angular.module('graphMeDota2App')
      .service('MatchesService', ['$http', 'config', function ($http, config) {
```